# We need an `offload_dir` to dispatch this model according to this `device_map`

Tags: python, directory, llama

anyone know how to fix this error, heres the python code it keeps giving me the error on.

model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(output_dir, device_map="auto", torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16)

This image is the rror in full. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87GZz.png)

I'm trying to run llama 2 on google colab, more specifically I'm trying to fine tune the model and run it. I'm new to this so I have no idea how you would go about solving this.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)